# ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer when cloning 15 git submodules inside docker

Tags: ssh, git, docker

I have a git project with 15 submodules. When I run

```
docker run --rm -it my-build-docker bash
git clone super-project
cd super-project
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

this runs 15 `git clone` commands under the hood; in very fast succession. Many of these `git clone` commands fail with:

```
Cloning into '/super-project/submodule1'...
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

---

## setup

I can reproduce this only on one machine, on two other machines everything runs fine, and I am failing to find the reason. I am running the exact same **my-build-docker** everywhere.

### failing server

- centos 7 (barebone)
- docker 18.06 (fails with 19.03 also)

**NOTE** : When I run the git clones natively on the **failing-server**, it runs fine!

### working server 1

- centos 7 (VM)
- docker 18.06 (works with 18.09 also)

### working server 2

- opensuse 15.0
- docker 18.09

Answer (score 0):

I my case this was due to `xinetd` configuration. I had to change **/etc/xinetd.conf** on our server to contain:

```
per_source      = 100
```

then restart xinetd.